# How to fetch quote_path value in associative array where the key may vary in a dynamic loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to fetch the value based on a specific key. The key comes in a loop, but the index of the key varies. For one case it can be 48 for other it can be 50. Sharing the array below-

```
 [info_buyRequest] => Array
            (
                [uenc] => aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9TdGlja2VyaXR3ZWIvY3VzdG9tLXN0aWNrZXJzL3RyYW5zZmVyLXN0aWNrZXJzLmh0bWw,
                [product] => 12
                [selected_configurable_option] => 
                [related_product] => 
                [qty] => 1
                [custom_quantity] => 500
                [custom_price1] => 303
                [options] => Array
                    (
                        [47] => 
                        [48] => Black
                        [49] => 8x10 cm
                        [51] => 
                        [76] => 500 pcs
                        [50] => Array
                            (
                                [type] => image/png
                                [title] => project_it_Side_Logo.png
                                [quote_path] => custom_options/quote/S/t/056de63143470f3907e354cd38f2dd3a.png
                                [order_path] => custom_options/order/S/t/056de63143470f3907e354cd38f2dd3a.png
                                [fullpath] => /var/www/html/project/pub/media/custom_options/quote/S/t/056de63143470f3907e354cd38f2dd3a.png
                                [size] => 57385
                                [width] => 1294
                                [height] => 353
                                [secret_key] => 056de63143470f3907e3
                            )

                    )

                [skipbutton] => 0
            )
```

Comment: `$yourObjectName["info_buyRequest"]["options"][50]["quote_path"]` should do it.

Comment: will there be always one array in array 'options'?

Comment: @ADyson I guess he means the position is going to be dynamic..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo hmm I suppose that's possible. But if that's the meaning, it's very badly worded...

Comment: But Option[50] value change then how i find this value

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yes always in options but number will we change

Comment: @AmanMehra added an answer

Comment: Hi All, It will be great if my thumbs down are removed, as I am new to stack so learning slowly. Please comment what I put wrong in question instead of thumbs down.

Comment: @AmanMehra actually if you hover over the "downvote" button any question, a popover appers and you can see the reasons for which downvotes can be given. People are not required to comment. But if I had to guess, I would suggest it's because the wording of your question is not clear (hence why Danyal and I had to discuss it), and also potentially because you don't appear to have made any effort to research or solve it yourself - generally people here don't want to spend their free time to do work for people who have no intention of spending their own time on it first.

Comment: @ADyson your comment makes sense to me. But as I am new to stack so I didn't knew the correct protocol and I do no fall under the 'generally' thing. The resultant to your downvotes is that now, I am not able to - 
Ask a new question,
Delete the Question,
Edited the question but no impact
So I may have to create a new user ID to post a new question. To me this is very unwelcoming for the new user. Specially the one's who come here for help.

Comment: @AmanMehra Actually I personally didn't downvote you but I'm sorry that has happened. I think probably you can regain your reputation either by deleting this question, or by answering other questions and gaining upvotes. Then the ban may be lifted. Or it may be lifted again after a period of time. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans for more info.  P.S. Everyone who asks a question is coming here for help, but if you don't ask **good** questions then it's unsurprising if you don't get a very warm welcome...I don't see a big issue with that TBH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. It's working for you.

```
$options = $objectName["info_buyRequest"]["options"];
$quotePaths = [];

foreach($options as $option){
   if( is_array ($option) && isset($option['quote_path'])){
     $quotePaths[] = $option['quote_path'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the `options` array, and find the array using `is_array` like this:

```
$array = $yourObjectName["info_buyRequest"]["options"];
$innerArray = array();
foreach($array as $value){
   if( is_array ($value)){
     $innerArray = $value;
     break;
   }

}
```